# Sentinel-2 files opening in SNAP

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-snap

I see that others have problems similar to mine. Attempts to open Sentinel-2 data in SNAP by means of the *.xml file(s) fail. 
When I pick the xml file from here, supposed to be metadata file,
the answer is: `"No appropriate Product Reader found"`

If I pick the xml file from the subdirectory “DATASTRIP/S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_DS_SGS_...”, the answer is the same.

Is this due to error during downloading or dezipping? If so, how can this be avoided?

Comment: I have notice the same problem with dezipped files. I keep the ZIP file and open it in SNAP and then it works perfect. I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SNAP are you using?

Which kind of METADATA (`*.xml`) file have your scenes?

From almost a year ago, metadata naming convention changed and old versions of SNAP don't support that kind of structure. The old version was named as `S2A_OPER_*.xml`, now all scenes have the same metadata name: `MTD_MSIL1C.xml` (check [product description](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/documents/247904/685211/Sentinel-2-Product-Specifications-Document) file). [In this threat](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/need-help-for-opening-sentinel-2-data/6211), this topic is addressed.

I recommend you to delete old version of SNAP after upgrading to the [new one](http://step.esa.int/main/download/).

Comment: This was interesting, I didn't know about this New Version (6.0, I downloaded ver 5.0 two weeks ago. The metafiles I try to open is probably of the old type, the name begins with S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL...., but the directory containing the files is named S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_... I will try the 6.0 Version, and to open it from the zip file